# Get data-id from html element

Tags: html, testing, css-selectors, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm trying to extract the content of data-id.
For example :

```
<div data-id= "43434"></div>
```

How can I get the value of 43434? I want to get access to the content of data.

Comment: Please mention what you tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

As I see you want to get this value inside a TestCafe test.

If so you can use the [Selector.getAttribute()](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/dom-node-state.html) method.

```
const element   = Selector('your-div-selector');
const attrValue = await element.getAttribute('data-id');

// or if you need to use it in an assertion
await t.expect(element.getAttribute('data-id')).eql('43434');
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the element using [has attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and get the value from [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property or get attribute value using [`Element#getAttribte`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method.

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector('div[data-id]').dataset.id
)
```

```html
<div data-id="43434"></div>
```